# Sencha CMD - How build only MODERN app from Admin Dashboard template?

Tags: extjs, cmd

I would like to build a mobile app from the Admin Dashboard template (only for testing purpouse).

First I created my app using the following script:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ext>sencha generate app -s templates/admin-dashboard app ../myApp
```

This works fine! The app was created together with its tree folders in the `\htdocs\myApp` path.
After that, I made some changes to the views and run the following script:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp>sencha app build modern production
```

But I get the following error:

```
[LOG] Build error for C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\build\temp\production\Admin\sass\Admin-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion Error : list_item_title__mix is not defined :
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR]   at org.apache.tools.ant
[ERR] .TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 1 minute 11 seconds

[ERR] C:\Users\silve\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.1.0.15\plugin.xml:333: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\silve\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.1.0.15\ant\build\app\build-impl.xml:292: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\silve\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.1.0.15\ant\build\app\sass-impl.xml:205: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\silve\bin\Sencha\Cmd\7.1.0.15\ant\build\app\sass-impl.xml:240: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: Fashion build exited with code : 1
[ERR] A log is available in the file "C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp\sencha-error-20200411.log"
```

Can someone explain where the problem is, please?

If I remove the "modern" specification everything works fine, but, I don't need the classic toolkit because the final device will be a cell phone.

I tried without success with:

- `sencha app build modern production`
- `sencha app build -modern -e production`

Comment: Hi mkrieger1, currently I had the same issue: "list_item_title__mix is not defined", after build modern to production.
I don't find any solution... do you remember how solve it?
Thanks in advanced!!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use --modern ([docs](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/advanced_cmd/cmd_reference.html)). It is used once during application generation.

In your case, there is a problem with scss

```
Admin-all.scss
[LOG] Fashion Error : list_item_title__mix is not defined :
[ERR]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this problem is solved in the same way for everyone, but I encountered the same error when I removed this line from the application file (Admin.Application):

```
mainView: 'Admin.view.main.Main',
```

To solve this problem I added this class name to the "requires" array:

```
Ext.define('Admin.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    requires: [
        'Admin.view.main.Main'
    ],
    
    name: 'Admin',

    defaultToken : 'dashboard',

    profiles: [
        'Phone',
        'Tablet'
    ],
............
```

I will be glad if this solution is useful to someone.